# TensorFlow GPU 1.10 not working with CUDA 9.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

As in title - I have installed TensorFlow GPU 1.10 and CUDA 9.0 - and they are not working. Traceback from Pycharm 2018.2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 87, in preload_check
    ctypes.WinDLL(build_info.cudnn_dll_name)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ctypes__init__.py", line 348, in **init**
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] Nie można odnaleźć określonego modułu

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/Documents/PycharmProjects/DL_Tensor_Flow_Beggining/TF_Neural_Network.py", line 2, in 
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 22, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 49, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 30, in 
    self_check.preload_check()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 97, in preload_check
    % (build_info.cudnn_dll_name, build_info.cudnn_version_number))
ImportError: Could not find 'cudnn64_7.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Note that installing cuDNN is a separate step from installing CUDA, and this DLL is often found in a different directory from the CUDA DLLs. You may install the necessary DLL by downloading cuDNN 7 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn

Process finished with exit code 1

I checked CUDA 9 files and there is no 'cudnn64_7.dll' file.
Only cud....dll files there are are: cudart32_90 and cudart64_90

What should I do?

<<>>
I have downloaded CUDnn 9.0 and I've added it as a environmental variable - still same error.

Specification of laptop: Win10, 8GB DDR4, Nvidia GTX 1050, i7 7700HQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should also have cudnn on your computer as the error code says. Please see: https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn

Comment: OK. After installing it I will let you know if it helped.

Comment: I have added this dll as environment variable and still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION FOR THE SECOND ERROR:

We've just been able to reproduce the same error, and it was caused by a missing MSVCP140.dll. (Thanks @wolffg!) Installing the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3 (x64 version) should fix it. Can you please try that and let us know if it works?

Answer from: [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5949)

So to conclude - for other people with this problem - if you're getting error from question - check both @Dawid_Sielski,  my first and my second answer (this one) to get rid of this problem.

Thanks to you all!